# Every simple graph with no loops and more than one vertex has at least 2 vertices of the same degree.

Tags: graph-theory

I've been given the following statement, I need to decide if it's true/false and if true, prove it:

> Every simple graph with no loops and more than one vertex has at least 2 vertices of the same degree.

Could you guys give me some general advise on how to start these kind of proofs and some hints?

I just started learning graph theory, so these kind of proofs seem pretty hard.

Comment: Suppose we have a (connected) graph with 3 vertices. What degrees can a vertex have? What if we have a graph with 4 vertices? 5? See if you notice a pattern

Comment: This problem for connected graphs was already considered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130634/prove-that-undirected-connected-graph-w-v-2-2-nodes-have-same-degree).  If some component of a not-necessarily connected graph has at least two vertices, then that would apply.  The case where no component has more than one vertex leads to a trivial solution.

Comment: As you can see, the two arguments provided below are the same two arguments given on the previous Question.  One looks at a degree sequence and quickly derives a contradiction; the other dresses up this same contradiction a bit by invoking the Pigeonhole Principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, suppose contrary that there exists a **finite** simple graph on $n$ vertices such that no two vertices have the same degree.  Then, each degree in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ occurs exactly once.  Hence, there is a vertex with degree $0$ and there is a vertex of degree $n-1$.  See a contradiction here?

Comment: The degree $n-1$ vertex is touching everybody but there's a vertex that's not being touched, right?

Comment: You are correct with your reasoning.  However, "touching" sounds too sensual for vertices of graphs.  A good term is "being adjacent."

Comment: I see, do you need to assume the graph here is connected? I think you need to, won't that cause a loss of generality?

Comment: This solution does not assume connectedness.  Otherwise, I wouldn't have talked about vertices of degree $0$.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that a minute after posting that, sorry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** The [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) states that, when putting $n$ objects in $m$ containers, when $n > m$, there must be a container with more than one object in it. Or, put in another way, there must be at least two objects in the same container.

**SOLUTION:** Now, here we have to find two vertices with the same degree. The Pigeonhole Principle could be useful, as long as we figure out which are the objects and which are the containers.

Well, the $n$ vertices in our graph could be our objects, and we put a vertex in container $i$ if it has degree $i$. Now we just have to show that the number $m$ of containers is less than $n$, and we are done.

What is the maximum degree of a vertex? It can be connected to all other $n-1$ vertices, so $n-1$. What is the minimum degree of a vertex? It can be isolated (not connected to any other vertex), so $0$.

Oh no! Now we have $n$ possible containers, one per number between $0$ and $n-1$. But wait: can there be **both** a vertex connected to *every* other vertex, and a vertex connected to *no* other vertex? Clearly not (do you see why?). So we have at most $n-1$ containers, and we are done.