# Vertices of equal degree in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have found the proof that if G is a simple graph with order $n\geq 2$ then there are at least two vertices in $V(G)$ that have equal degree. Does this statement extend to non-simple graphs? If so, how do I go about proving it? Thank you

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130634/prove-that-undirected-connected-graph-w-v-2-2-nodes-have-same-degree

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you construct a graph with three vertices $a,b,c$.

$a$ is having a self loop and is connected to $b$, $b$ is having a self loop and connected to $c$.

Degree($a$) =$ 3$,  Degree($b$) =$ 4$, Degree($c$) =$1$